# Scrapy returns no output - just a [

Tags: json, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm trying to run the spider found in this [crawler](https://github.com/jmdalmeida/SentimentAnalysis/tree/master/crawler/texteval) and for simplicity sake I'm using this [start_url](http://www.imdb.com/search/title?countries=csxx&sort=moviemeter,asc) because it is just a list of 320 movies. (So, the crawler won't run for 5 hours as given in the github page).

I crawl using `scrapy crawl imdb -o output.json` but the output.json file contains nothing. It has just a `[` in it.

```
import scrapy
from texteval.items import ImdbMovie, ImdbReview
import urlparse
import math
import re

class ImdbSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "imdb"
    allowed_domains = ["imdb.com"]
    start_urls = [
        # "http://www.imdb.com/chart/top",
        # "http://www.imdb.com/chart/bottom"
        "http://www.imdb.com/search/title?countries=csxx&sort=moviemeter,asc"
    ]
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.robotstxt.ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True,
}
base_url = "http://www.imdb.com"

def parse(self, response):
    movies = response.xpath("//*[@id='main']/table/tr/td[3]/a/@href")
    for i in xrange(len(movies)):
        l = self.base_url + movies[i].extract()
        print l
        request = scrapy.Request(l, callback=self.parse_movie)
        yield request

    next = response.xpath("//*[@id='right']/span/a")[-1]
    next_url = self.base_url + next.xpath(".//@href")[0].extract()
    next_text = next.xpath(".//text()").extract()[0][:4]
    if next_text == "Next":
        request = scrapy.Request(next_url, callback=self.parse)
        yield request
    '''
    for sel in response.xpath("//table[@class='chart']/tbody/tr"):
        url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, sel.xpath("td[2]/a/@href").extract()[0].strip())
        request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_movie)
        yield request
    '''

def parse_movie(self, response):
    movie = ImdbMovie()
    i1 = response.url.find('/tt') + 1
    i2 = response.url.find('?')
    i2 = i2 - 1 if i2 > -1 else i2
    movie['id'] = response.url[i1:i2]
    movie['url'] = "http://www.imdb.com/title/" + movie['id']
    r_tmp = response.xpath("//div[@class='titlePageSprite star-box-giga-star']/text()")
    if r_tmp is None or r_tmp == "" or len(r_tmp) < 1:
        return
    movie['rating'] = int(float(r_tmp.extract()[0].strip()) * 10)
    movie['title'] = response.xpath("//span[@itemprop='name']/text()").extract()[0]
    movie['reviews_url'] = movie['url'] + "/reviews"
    # Number of reviews associated with this movie
    n = response.xpath("//*[@id='titleUserReviewsTeaser']/div/div[3]/a[2]/text()")
    if n is None or n == "" or len(n) < 1:
        return
    n = n[0].extract().replace("See all ", "").replace(" user reviews", "")\
        .replace(" user review", "").replace(",", "").replace(".", "").replace("See ", "")
    if n == "one":
        n = 1
    else:
        n = int(n)
    movie['number_of_reviews'] = n
    r = int(math.ceil(n / 10))
    for x in xrange(1, r):
        start = x * 10 - 10
        url = movie['reviews_url'] + "?start=" + str(start)
        request = scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_review)
        request.meta['movieObj'] = movie
        yield request

def parse_review(self, response):
    ranks = response.xpath("//*[@id='tn15content']/div")[0::2]
    texts = response.xpath("//*[@id='tn15content']/p")
    del texts[-1]
    if len(ranks) != len(texts):
        return

    for i in xrange(0, len(ranks) - 1):
        review = ImdbReview()
        review['movieObj'] = response.meta['movieObj']
        review['text'] = texts[i].xpath("text()").extract()
        rating = ranks[i].xpath(".//img[2]/@src").re("-?\\d+")
        if rating is None or rating == "" or len(rating) < 1:
            return
        review['rating'] = int(rating[0])
        yield review
```

Can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this web site should be load the list of movies use by js. Fristly, I suggest you should check the output about: `movies = response.xpath("//*[@id='main']/table/tr/td[3]/a/@href")`. If you want to get js content, you can use webkit in scrapy as a downloader middleware.